# ShowcaseView ConfigOptions for a list of targets

Tags: android, showcaseview

Cannot find any documentation on how to config ShowcaseView.

This is from [ShowcaseView GitHub pages](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/):

> Usage
>
> To use ShowcaseView, use one of the insertShowcaseView(..) calls. These take:
>
> - A [Target](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/blob/target/library/src/com/espian/showcaseview/targets/Target.java) which represents what should be showcased. See the [wiki](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView/wiki/Target-API) for more details.
> - An Activity
> - Optional title and detail strings (or resource ids) which show on the ShowcaseView
> - Optional a [ConfigOptions](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/blob/master) which can alter the behaviour of ShowcaseView. See the wiki for more details

The only working link is the wiki one, where i cannot find anything about ConfigOptions and how to use it, other links are broken.

I'm trying to write down a little tutorial for my app, here's what I deduced by studying the source code:

```
        ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions co = new ShowcaseView.ConfigOptions();
        co.hideOnClickOutside = false;
        //show only first one once?!
        co.shotType = ShowcaseView.TYPE_ONE_SHOT;
        co.showcaseId=1;
        co.centerText=true;
        co.noButton=false;
        co.block = true;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lps = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        lps.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        lps.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        int margin = 10;
        lps.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
        co.buttonLayoutParams = lps;

        ShowcaseViews svs = new ShowcaseViews(this);
        ShowcaseViews.ItemViewProperties ivp;
        ivp= new ItemViewProperties(
                R.id.target1,
                R.string.target1_tit,
                R.string.target1_desc,
                0.4f,
                co
            );
        svs.addView(ivp);

        co.showcaseId=2;
        ivp= new ItemViewProperties(
                R.id.target2,
                R.string.target2_tit,
                R.string.target2_desc,
                0.4f,
                co
            );
        svs.addView(ivp);

        co.showcaseId=3;
        ivp= new ItemViewProperties(
                R.id.target3,
                R.string.target3_tit,
                R.string.target3_desc,
                0.4f,
                co
            );
        svs.addView(ivp);

        svs.show();
```

but i cannot figure out many things:

1. how to place title and message strings at the center of the screen (ConfigOption.centerText has no effect?)
2. how to resize text (i would like it bigger)
3. how to place the OK button elsewhere (ConfigOption.buttonLayoutParams has no effect)
4. how to dismiss showcase (or display next one) when user touches the target view

thanx.

Answer (score 1):

> how to place the OK button elsewhere (ConfigOption.buttonLayoutParams has no effect)

This is the only thing I know of:

```
svs.setButtonPosition( LAYOUTPARAMS OBJECT HERE );
```